# Deny direct URL request to files in specific folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi there just wondering;

How do I deny direct access to files in a specific folder. I have an upload script that uploads to `/uploadedFiles` and currently I just have an *index.php* which redirects the user to the login page. However, how do I stop users from accessing a file directly such as:

```
/uploadedFiles/thisFile.jpeg
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want your files to be accessed via the webinterface, add a `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: Is there any way to allow users that have signed into the website to access the files in the directory but not those who haven't authenticated?

Comment: Unless you use BasicAuth for your login procedure, you might to try to send the file via your application (readfile in PHP, sendfile in Ruby/Rails or X-Sendfile). Those methods do not check the contents of the `.htaccess` file.